# django unable to connect with postgres from docker container

Tags: django, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.8
ARG index_url

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
WORKDIR /usr/src/report_backend

COPY ./ /usr/src/report_backend

RUN apt-get -y update

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

docker-compose file

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
```

django db settings

```
DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2",
        "NAME": "story",
        "USER": "monetree",
        "PASSWORD": "Thinkonce",
        "HOST": "dev.report.inergio.io",
        "PORT": 5432
    },
}
```

Here i am trying to connect local server database.
but i am getting below error

```
web_1  |     self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 25, in inner
web_1  |     return func(*args, **kwargs)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 199, in get_new_connection
web_1  |     connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 122, in connect
web_1  |     conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
web_1  | django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL:  database "story" does not exist
```

here is my database. database already exist but it is not working .

```
psql (12.9 (Ubuntu 12.9-0ubuntu0.20.04.1))
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# 
postgres=# \l
                              List of databases
    Name     |  Owner   | Encoding | Collate |  Ctype  |   Access privileges   
-------------+----------+----------+---------+---------+-----------------------
postgres    | postgres | UTF8     | C.UTF-8 | C.UTF-8 | 
story       | postgres | UTF8     | C.UTF-8 | C.UTF-8 | =Tc/postgres         +
            |          |          |         |         | postgres=CTc/postgres+
            |          |          |         |         | monetree=CTc/postgres
story_files | postgres | UTF8     | C.UTF-8 | C.UTF-8 | =Tc/postgres         +
            |          |          |         |         | postgres=CTc/postgres+
            |          |          |         |         | monetree=CTc/postgres
template0   | postgres | UTF8     | C.UTF-8 | C.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
            |          |          |         |         | postgres=CTc/postgres
template1   | postgres | UTF8     | C.UTF-8 | C.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
            |          |          |         |         | postgres=CTc/postgres
(5 rows)

postgres=# \q
```

http://dev.report.inergio.io/ is my host so i am using this inside my settings.
please take a look what can be the issue ?

Comment: to be clear your postgres is on local and i can see from the compose file you have your app dockerized. could you please try exposing 5432 and map it to 5432.

Comment: i see. rest all is correct right ?

Comment: where is your postgres container in `docker-compose`?

Comment: No. It is in local server. Not inside container

Comment: @SoubhagyaPradhan pleas try that and post here if its all good to go.

Comment: it is working now. had to open port

Comment: glad to hear that, please mark the question as closed.